# How to add an Owner to Registered Application in Azure AD

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

We have a "Registered Application" in our Azure Active Directory, however, the old owner has been deleted from our account (he left the company).

Unfortunately, we can't restore the user, and no one in the company can manage the application because it doesn't have an owner anymore.

Although we can see the application in "Enterprise Applications", we can't see it in "App Registrations", and we can't add new keys, etc.

Is there a way, through Powershell, or any other interface, to add a new owner to this application so that we can use it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a discussion in the comments, we discovered the app is actually a multi-tenant app registered in another directory.

That's why it only showed up under Enterprise applications.
When you enable a multi-tenant application in a directory,
a Service Principal (Enterprise application) is created in there.
The Application (where owners are registered) remains in the original directory where it was registered.

---

If you are a Global Admin, you can see the app.

You need to make sure you select **All apps** on the App registrations tab.

[image: My apps All apps dropdown]

As an alternative, you can add an owner by using Azure AD PowerShell cmdlets: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.1.3

```
Connect-AzureAD
Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId 3ddd22e7-a150-4bb3-b100-e410dea1cb84 -RefObjectId c13dd34a-492b-4561-b171-40fcce2916c5
```

`ObjectId` should be the object id of the application, you can get it by listing the applications with `Get-AzureADApplication`.
The second parameter, `RefObjectId` should be the object id of the user you want to add.
You should be able to get that from the portal, or with `Get-AzureADUser`.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to help.  Maybe I'm not a global admin, though I created the account...

Comment: Hmm, okay that is weird. AAD PowerShell cmdlets would be an option too. I'll edit those in.

Comment: Yes, I am a global administrator, but the app is not displayed there.  It's like that part of it got deleted along with the user that owned it

Comment: It should not, the relation between the user and application is deleted.

Comment: In addition to PS, you can try [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). You can log in and get apps with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications`.

Comment: BTW, I appreciate you helping.  This is what the cmdlet says: https://gist.github.com/synic/6721397c97bbbeab04840d246f5f3bcf .  I'm able to obtain the app just fine using `$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq 'SomeApp SSO'"`, but then it says the app doesn't exist when I try to assign an owner.

Comment: Hmm... What does it say for the app publisher in Enterprise apps? I'm thinking could it be a multi-tenant app from another tenant.

Comment: And yeah, you need the applications id, not the service principal's id.

Comment: You are correct.  It is from another tenant.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a  Global Admin you can go through the portal to assign a new owner to the application.

Here are steps to do so via this documentation https://aka.ms/Lcdcm6

1. Open the **Azure Active Directory Extension** by clicking **All services** at the top of the main left hand navigation menu.
2. Type in **“Azure Active Directory”** in the filter search box and select the **Azure Active Directory** item.
3. Click **Enterprise Applications** from the **Azure Active Directory** left hand navigation menu.
4. Click **All Applications** to view a list of all your applications.

   -If you do not see the application you want show up here, use the **Filter** control at the top of the **All Applications List** and set the **Show** option to **All Applications**.
5. Select the application you want to assign a user to from the list.
6. Once the application loads, click **Users and Groups** from the application’s left hand navigation menu.
7. Click the **Add** button on top of the **Users and Groups** list to open the **Add Assignment** pane.
8. Click the **Users and Groups** selector from the **Add Assignment** pane.
9. Type in the **full name or email address** of the user you are interested in assigning into the **Search by name or email address** search box.
10. Hover over the **user** in the list to reveal a checkbox. Click the **checkbox** next to the user’s profile photo or logo to add your user to the **Selected** list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Grace, what is the purpose of the AZURE > Enterprise Application > Owners?  If you add a User or Group what capabilities do they have?  --- Just after posting I performed the correct search and this is what I got - An Enterprise Application Owner can "manage 'owned' enterprise applications, including SSO settings, user and group assignments, and adding additional owners," Microsoft explained. ... There's also a new Application Developer role, which gets assigned through the Azure AD Portal or Azure AD Privileged Identity Management.