# What happens if I have an App Registration in Azure and the App owners account is disabled?

Tags: azure

What happens if I have an App registration in Azure and the Owner's account gets disabled? Will the app registration continue to work?

Comment: It is recommended to have several owners in a subscription. the Admin account is on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the app registration continue to work?

The application is still valid. In fact, when you register an application in Azure, it is equivalent to the entire tenant-level registration. Even if the account of the owner of the application is disabled, other users can still log in to the application,  and the application is still valid in the entire tenant .

Answer (score 0):

The app registration continues to work.

> When a user creates a new application registration they are automatically added as the first owner. Ownership permissions give the user the ability to manage all aspects of an application registration or enterprise application that they own. The original owner can be removed and additional owners can be added.

Answer (score 0):

App Owners merely have access to manage the application. The application itself will continue to work but if this Owner was the only one listed with that App Registration, only a Global Admin will have access

When you look at the Owner tab you see this:

> In addition to users with permission to manage any applications, the users listed here can view and edit this application registration.

This says that in addition to those added as Owners, those with permissions to manage any applications (e.g. Global Admins) can view and edit the application.

So if the Owner's account is disabled or deleted after he has left the company, you could get the Global Admin to assign someone else or manage the application themself.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498953/how-to-add-an-owner-to-registered-application-in-azure-ad) post also mentions some of this.