# Azure App Registrations - How to change owner?

Tags: azure, authentication

Under [Azure](https://portal.azure.com/#allservices) "[App Registrations](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade)" I have an application under "Applications from personal account".
I accidentally created this application (which is now in production) under my personal email address, and not the company email address.

Now that I am leaving the company, I would like to move this application to a different account, so that others in the company may have access to it.

If I hit the application, then "Owners", I see:

> This app does not belong to any directory, so owners can’t be added to it.

[image]

I know what directory I would like to put it in (The company's directory ID), but, I can't find how to actually move the applications to a different directory, owner, or anything.

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499120/4317508

Comment: @Amit Could you include the Portal screenshot of application by editing your question?

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps thanks, but can't find the parallel.

Comment: @Sridevi added screenshot, thanks

Comment: @Amit I thought that your Application was a multi-tenant app registered in another directory

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. As you point out the application is in production I take the following assumption:

- The app is a multi-tenant app
- It's already used by multiple different organizations (=the companies customers or partners)
- The application is in frequent use
- The application does not have permission in a tenant to create new service principals / accept grant access rights to new applications

What I would do in your case:

1. Create a new application in the Company directory and make sure it matches the "original" one as good as possible (probably copy the manifest and adapt where necessary).
2. Create a powershell script which Tenant administratos can use to migrate the "old" (=the app registration in your tenant) users including their permissions to the new one. This makes sure users keep their permissions and at least for the users the shift is as smooth as possible.
3. If the application is developed inhouse and well architected, extend it by supporting sign-in with both app-registrations and add a Warning/Info/.... explaining the necessary changes to be done by people privileged enough. Best add a deadline to know until when the migration is done. If it's not developed inhouse/not well architectured/a lot of work to add this functionality it depends on the relationship to your customers/partners and stuff on how much to spend on this.